Different definition of Feller semi-group
Let $E$ be a locally compact metric space, let $C_0(E)$ be the set of real-valued continuous functions of $E$ vanishing at infinity endowed with the sup norm $|\cdot|_{\infty}$, let $C_b(E)$ be the set of real-valued continuous and bounded functions of $E$ endowed with the sup norm. Let $(P_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Feller semi-group. Depending on sources (see this discussion for example), a Feller semi-group maps (i) $C_0(E) \to C_0(E)$ or (ii) $C_b(E) \to C_b(E)$. My question is : does (i) imply (ii) ? If the space $E$ is compact, it is true as $C_b(E) = C_0(E)$. I am interested in the case where $E$ is not compact.
I have tried all the tricks in my book and I cannot prove it. However, I cannot find a counter-example as well. The reverse is not true, take the example from the already mentionned discussion
$$P_tf(x) = f\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2t + x^{-2}}}\right)$$
associated to the deterministic process $d_t x(t) = - x^3$. We have $P_t : C_b(\mathbb{R}_+) \to C_b(\mathbb{R}_+)$ but not $P_t : C_0(\mathbb{R}_+) \to C_0(\mathbb{R}_+)$.
My questions stems from the fact that (ii) is sometimes called weak-Feller (for example in page 8-9 of Markov Chains on Metric Space, Benaim et al.) which to me suggest that (i) would imply (ii). With (ii) comes continuity of $x \mapsto P_t(x,\cdot)$ with respect to the weak convergence topology of probability measure which is a useful property, and I would like to know if it actually also apply to (i).

Welcome to Math StackExchange. Here we expect askers to ask good questions, that show efforts and where the problems appear. Could you provide more context and information about what you've tried and where you were stuck?
